# How to disable Windows Defender Application Control once and for all?

Tags: windows-10, security, group-policy, windows-defender, secure-boot

*(Please read before marking this as a duplicate, thanks.)*

#### Description

I am developing my own Win32 x86_64 application which interferes heavily with the system, is able to communicate with drivers through Win32 APIs and needs administrator access. Still it's a valid Win32 application (not a driver!) that I want to test on my local machine like every other application I'm developing. Nothing extraordinary I'm doing here.

This specific application can't be started because of this error message:

```
Your organization used Windows Defender Application Control to block this app.
<path to exe file>
Contact your support person for more info.
```

As this is a local development machine not being part of any domain I'm wondering why it even says "organization" but well... just Windows 10 things I guess.

What I did to get it running is (and none of it helped):

- Disabling Secure Boot
- Disabling Windows Defender Application Guard
- Disabling Windows Defender
- Disabling anything related to Windows Defender in the Settings app
- Disabling anything related to Windows Defender via `gpedit`
- Making sure that `App & browser control` is disabled
- Adding the application as an exception in Windows Defender (even though it's turned off)
- Disabling signed driver enforcement via `gpedit`
- Disabling policies according to [this MSDN documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/disable-windows-defender-application-control-policies)
- Validated that I never ran and am not running a Windows 10 S variant
- Enabling test signing
- Following a bazillion tutorials: [1](https://winbuzzer.com/2020/08/11/windows-defender-application-guard-how-to-turn-it-on-or-off-xcxwbt/), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV-URyeYauo), [3](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/organization-used-windows-defender-application-control-block-app/), [4](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-disable-app-and-browser-control-windows-10/1c364d63-acca-4354-9841-447b7b3ff084), [5](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_updating-windows_10/your-organization-used-windows-defender/ef12b7be-41f5-4b71-a73c-e4f99ba944f7), [6](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-windows-defender-using-defender-control)
- Trying to start the same application on a different notebook
- Trying to start the same application on a *freshly installed* Windows 10 Pro 21H1 VM (to validate the problem)
- Sending the application to a friend to test it on his machine

None of the above worked. The only configuration I could get the application started with is enabling test signing AND signing my application with a test certificate. Just signing it without test signing enabled gives the same error.

This is plainly unacceptable. I'm not dealing with a driver here but a normal Win32 application so test signing shouldn't need to be enabled. I don't feel comfortable having test signing enabled (and thus Secure Boot disabled) on my daily-used development machine.

I'd be fine with just signing it and getting it started. What even baffles me more is that I am not able to disable this Windows Defender Application Control even though [it doesn't even seem to be installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbICA.png).

#### Question

**How can I get rid of Windows Defender Application Control once and for all?**

#### Environment

- Fully activated, legal Windows 10 Pro 21H1 x64 (latest updates applied)
- Visual Studio 2019 16.10
- Application is compiled for x86_64

Comment: Try to disable the Windows Defender Security Center app by renaming `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_cw5n1h2txyewy` and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc Nice idea, sadly no effect. Also moving that folder to somewhere else didn't work.

Comment: Try maybe to install  another antivirus, so Windows Defender might fully disable itself.

Comment: @harrymc Tried two different AVs now, no effect.

Comment: (1) This [article](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/10/25/how-to-disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10-permanently/) might have a few methods that you haven't tried. (2) Did you set in Services to disabled Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection Service. (3) Disable also Windows Defender Firewall. (4) Nuke folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.2104.14-0` and reboot. (5) It might be better to disconnect the internet while testing all this.

Comment: (1) I applied all now except NoDefender because the download doesn't work. (2) Not possible, "access denied" even when starting `services.msc` as admin. But it's not running, its startup is set to `Manual`. (3) Disabled now. (4) The folder `4.18.2104.14-0` was not there, deleted the `Platform` folder. Reboot done. None of it helped. Btw, I also tried rebooting with F8 and disabled driver signature enforcement there. No change...

Comment: The word "organization" means really "global policy". Which ones have you disabled?

Comment: `gpedit > Computer Configuration > Admin Templates > Win Components > Microsoft Defender Antivirus > Turn off Microsoft Defender Antivirus` set to `Enabled`

Comment: (1) Did you disable all *Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Manage settings option*? (2) Installed another antivirus, test that it's set as the Security provider in *Windows Security > Settings > Manage providers > Antivirus*. (3) Try [Defender Control](https://www.sordum.org/9480/defender-control-v1-9/) and [ConfigureDefender](https://github.com/AndyFul/ConfigureDefender).  (4) Rollback Windows Defender to previous version (I never tried it): [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-microsoft-defender-antimalware-platform-92e21611-8cf1-8e0e-56d6-561a07d144cc).

Comment: (5) See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174426/how-to-permanently-disable-windows-defender-real-time-protection-with-gpo).

Comment: (1) [I disabled everything I can disable](https://s20.directupload.net/images/210528/nff265ig.png). (2) Validated after reinstalling and yes, it's set as the provider as long as it's installed. (3) DefenderControl shows me a red banner = Defender is disabled. ConfigureDefender I disabled all I can. The Defender logs from ConfigureDefender also state that `Real-time protection`, `Windows Defender Antivirus scanning` and `malware and PUA scanning` are disabled. (4) It's not possible to rollback as I don't have that path available. (5) Did that. Reboot. No change.

Comment: Seems like Windows 10 Pro 21H1 nixed all the options. I can only suggest to use an earlier version and disable updates.

Comment: @harrymc did that. I tested it on 20H2 and 2004 and the behavior is exactly the same (I applied all things posted in this thread as well).

Comment: I don't think there are more known methods. You might need an even earlier version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your linker options and make sure you are not specifying the /INTEGRITYCHECK linker option. That option sets the Dll Characteristic "Check Integrity" in your binary which will change the way Windows/Defender performs the code integrity check when it loads it. You can even see the errors in the CodeIntegrity eventlog when Defender Application Controls blocks it.

Comment: Welcome to SU. While the answer might be correct, it's not very helpful for anyone who's not as familiar with Windows as you are. Adding clear step-by-step instructions on how to do this, with clarifying screenshots (you can upload them to Imgur or similar and paste the links here - someone will add them to the answer) would greatly improve it as even a dunce like me would be able to perform the task. Please see the [guidelines for answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777281/edit) your answer accordingly.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @Peregrino69 I get the sentiment but everyone who is dealing with this issue when building their own application knows what is meant with the answer. imo there is no further clarification needed.